# HTML5/Jquery - What is the correct way to preload audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a game which has a number of elements on a page, 
when the mouseover event on the element is triggered an audio file plays.

Its working, however,

My question is, What is the correct way to preload audio? 
So i can be sure that my audio plays as soon as the user interacts with the element.

I'm currently initialsing my audio object on mouseover

```
$('.circle').mouseover(function() {
    // retrieve ref from data- attribute
    var noteIndex = $(this).attr('data-note'); 

    // locate url from the array notes using noteIndex ref
    var snd = new Audio(notes[noteIndex]); 
    snd.play();
}
```

I'm aware of the Audio tags, but i'm unsure how that differs from my technique above.

EDIT : example of how i'm currently loading audio http://jsfiddle.net/kA5Bv/1/    (note the key doesn't play immediately, thats because the example audio files i've used has a gap of 1/2 second or so at the beginning)

Thanks in advance,
Cam

Answer (score 0):

What about the $(document).ready(function() {});, it will initialise your audio object on DOM load, before page contents are loaded.

Comment: The document ready function fires after the DOM is ready, so not before the contents are loaded. But it might be appropriate to preload the audio in that function.

Comment: the mouseover event is being added on $(document).ready, but does this mean the audio file loads when the mouseover event is added to the element or when the element event is triggered on mouseover. My guess is the latter would cause a lag on slower connections.

Comment: Its currently loading when theres a mouse-over event triggered on the element with circle class. If you remove that and just put the audio setup within the document.ready(), it will load when the dom is loaded

Comment: Ok, sorry i'm unsure how i'd implement that, i've updated the question with a jsfiddle, to better demonstrate how i'm referencing the notes with a unique identifier.